# Race Around the Track

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

I'm looking to find the fastest racer around. Show me your fastest lap around this 18x14 track shown below.

```
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
```

Your job is to move the car below around the track once in all possible positions.

```
 _
| |
|_|

 /\
/ /
\/

 __
|__|

/\
\ \
 \/
```

The car can drive in 3 spaces in a row before turning. Here's an example of what a lap should look like.

```
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /_  /      \   \
|| ||        |   |
||_||        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
| _ |        |   |
|| ||        |   |
||_||        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
| _ |        |   |
|| ||        |   |
||_||        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
| /\|        |   |
 \\ \\      /   /
  \\/ \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \ /\\      /   /
  \\ \\____/   /
   \\/        /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \ /\\____/   /
   \\ \       /
    \\/      /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \   __     /
    \ |__|   /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \    __    /
    \  |__|  /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \     __   /
    \   |__| /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____//\ /
   \       / //
    \      \//
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      //\ /
  \   \____// //
   \        \//
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |/\ |
 \   \      // //
  \   \____/ \//
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        | _ |
|   |        || ||
|   |        ||_||
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        | _ |
|   |        || ||
|   |        ||_||
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \  _\
|   |        || ||
|   |        ||_||
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \ /\\
 /   /      \\ \\
|   |        |\/ |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____ /\\
  /   /    \\ \\
 /   /      \\/ \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /      /\\
   /   ____\ \\
  /   /    \\/ \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /   __ \
    /   |__| \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /  __  \
    /  |__|  \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     / __   \
    / |__|   \
   /   ____   \
  /   /    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    //\      \
   // /____   \
  / \//    \   \
 /   /      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   //\ ____   \
  // //    \   \
 / \//      \   \
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
      ______
     /      \
    /        \
   /   ____   \
  //\ /    \   \
 // //      \   \
| \/|        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
|   |        |   |
 \   \      /   /
  \   \____/   /
   \          /
    \        /
     \______/
```

---

### Rules

- The output should show the car in all possible positions. 3 positions in each of the 8 sections of the track mean there are 24 possible positions to show.
- The car positions must be shown in sequence. (You can't teleport to another part of the track!)
- The starting position and direction (clockwise/counter clockwise) are not important.
- Output can be in any reasonable format for text.
- No input.
- Standard code-golf rules. The fewer bytes your code has, the faster your car runs.

Comment: I take it no or non-usable input?

Comment: @Veskah Correct. Edited the post to include this.

Comment: Very nice first challenge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 131 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
｛↔］
ø５／２２╋___７１╋__８４╋|¶|１７╋|¶|５７╋２／６５╋╬
３［⁵ __¶|__|²６＋２╋］
３［⁵ _¶| |¶|_|２５²＋╋］
３［⁵ /\¶/ /¶\/６²－２²＋╋］
⁷⁸⇵｛↕］∔⁶｛↕］∔⁸｛↕↔］∔⁷⇵⁴∔⁸⇵⁴∔⁶⁴∔⁸∔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=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,v=2)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 371 bytes

Rotates clockwise. Probably still golfable.

```javascript
f=(i=24,A=[])=>i--?A.map(r=>r.join``,g=(s,x,y)=>[...s].map(c=>(j=c.charCodeAt(),d='12221',m=k=>(x-=~-d[j&7],y-=~-d[j-2&7],k--)&&((A[y]=A[y]||Array(18).fill` `)[x]='|/_\\'[j&3],k&&m(k)))(j/8&7)),g('voF`ir@kBdm',5,1),g('fWF`Qb@SBdU',6,4),g(['NFPJAT','MDWFI@S','VFHRAL','UDOFQ@K'][i/3&3],'0x'+'111123678ABCEEECBA876321'[i],'0x'+'678BCDDDDEDC876654222567'[i])).join`
`+f(i):A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDbToNAEIbvfQqv2N24UIEWiMlWllM8a621F5QIQqnLoTTQNJA0vjouVedi8s/MNzOZyaJD1MQ12@3FbZWs@z4lkBFljCnxA0SmTBSvqVRGO1iTaS1lFduGId4Q2OAWdxzwJUlqghMRkynMSCzFX1Ft82F0DxFOCJAVRZEBLknOgVYk32LiZ4Ie4O5Pi8oQ5aKIBAFC6ncBGdzxSOs66qBsICllRRGeh8hvAwKOo4/VCvAZKu8ShBLmCCGYjQxBRwhvIDhUXshqM7eSEuAJlk/JdOmFs09zbiULgDU8HpI@ePJe7ugbwODRWXq35pyrd@/mlT5wsXCevZl5DwKfjdRhGbhswQWQuSmqphvUsl3XtS1q6JrKT/TZP8KLlu1wcx2bF7XJmP9goukDgtDvG8/CixQydEX7uNo2VbGWimoDU4hQ/wM)

#### Animated version

```js
f=(i=24,A=[])=>i--?A.map(r=>r.join``,g=(s,x,y)=>[...s].map(c=>(j=c.charCodeAt(),d='12221',m=k=>(x-=~-d[j&7],y-=~-d[j-2&7],k--)&&((A[y]=A[y]||Array(18).fill` `)[x]='|/_\\'[j&3],k&&m(k)))(j/8&7)),g('voF`ir@kBdm',5,1),g('fWF`Qb@SBdU',6,4),g(['NFPJAT','MDWFI@S','VFHRAL','UDOFQ@K'][i/3&3],'0x'+'111123678ABCEEECBA876321'[i],'0x'+'678BCDDDDEDC876654222567'[i])).join`
`+f(i):A

F = 0;
setInterval(_ => O.textContent = f().substr((F++ % 24) * 285 + 1, 285), 200)
```

```html
<pre id=O style="font-size:9px"></pre>
```

#### Less golfed

```javascript
// i = frame counter, A[] = drawing matrix
f = (i = 24, A = []) =>
  i-- ?
    A.map(r =>
      r.join``,
      // g() draws the shape described by s, starting at (x, y)
      g = (s, x, y) =>
        [...s].map(c => (
          // j holds the direction in bits 0-2 and the length in bits 3-5
          // a length of 0 means 'move without drawing'
          j = c.charCodeAt(),
          d = '12221',
          // m() either draws a line or just moves the pen by 1 step
          m = k => (
            x -= ~-d[j & 7],
            y -= ~-d[j - 2 & 7],
            k--
          ) && (
            (A[y] = A[y] || Array(18).fill` `)[x] = '|/_\\'[j & 3],
            k && m(k)
          )
        )(j / 8 & 7)),
      // draw the outer boundary of the track
      g('voF`ir@kBdm', 5, 1),
      // draw the inner boundary of the track
      g('fWF`Qb@SBdU', 6, 4),
      // draw the car, using the correct shape for this frame and hard-coded coordinates
      g(['NFPJAT', 'MDWFI@S', 'VFHRAL', 'UDOFQ@K'][i / 3 & 3],
        '0x'+'111123678ABCEEECBA876321'[i],
        '0x'+'678BCDDDDEDC876654222567'[i]
      )
    ).join`\n` + f(i)
  :
    A
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>641</s> <s>639</s> <s>592</s> 576 bytes

```python
for i in range(24):
 t='s  ______s  Xs / 642  \s Xs/875310  \sX   /:;8____   \   X  /<9:/s\   \  X />=</s  \   \ X|A@?|ss|   |X|BCB|ss|   |X|DED|ss|   |X|FHG|ss|   |X \ILK\s  /   / X  \KJM\____/   /  X   \MNPRTVs/   Xs\POQSUW  /sXs \______/s '.replace('s',4*' ')
 for c,C in[zip([chr(x)for x in range(48,88)],' '*ord(s)+r+' '*40)for s,r in zip("\0\n	!",'|____|?| ____|?\/\/?/\/\ ?\  / //\ ?_| ||_?_ | |_?_| ||_?\/\/\ ?\/\/?/  \ /\ ?| ____|?| ____|'.split('?'))][abs(12-i)]+zip('\/!','!\/')*(i>12):t=t.replace(c,C)
 print'\n'.join(l[::2*(i<13)-1]for l in t.split('X'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVBNT9tAEFVPVTlUlXpAgkMnXHY3MdnYuK0xCea7fEOhH5YykRVCAKPIsbw@ANr/HmZiQlYazby3szvzXv5cPowzbzK5GxeQQppB0c/uh9LzVbgAZUcYgGR6qIgNaPjhewBoCOjg5/c1t8UoBgAdbgTcSCVSEKXb66E2WBEx6M1OW5vqFiG221uRNcYSsrHd2d2Zg739vTk4OPz1DgCPTk9oOO3BQTPw5PgMeWzFMAV4dn559eefYSo2eHnx@/rvf7o1JAArNbSHaBbDfNQfDKUwwvHrAoRaAPZh4OySE92XNJfdwUMhnxSzT3N3/MAJAtVz6El9XNxKoxpFg4HfmrYap@Bm/mAFWx8@Yvbp85evi8tL32orjrC8gI0sVBk16ogCIUKWoLlKLFibRAlQTmYI37qmD9hDRrNv3rJomnyUllJEQqlet39jpOutpqrX4G0E6ppwRA21UHWZbrqeCstO@e4EKScP8iLNSoGZaD6O00yOumHoUXfbXVOrbo8FjlheORsV06jJ5BU)

- -2 bytes, thanks to Kevin Cruijssen
- -30 bytes, thanks to Mnemonic
- -16 bytes, thanks to Jonathan

Comment: [609 bytes](https://tio.run/##TVDbbptAEH3PV0we0O7aE68XqI1pHNokvaZp0zsSi5BruQ2VhRHwkFb77@4MxKqRhplzdi5npv7T3e8qf7//uWughLKCZlX92kg/VPEJdEvhtQBF/3GU0k/DLPQBLIUEdTR/Ephpj1MA0PHTiLMptGRE6fNFrL3WDkwK@mJ5rrnZwKTu@bPEea3XOsIudZdXl8fw@sX1MXz5@tURBPvm3Q0rIVVsNM7evL21rGBgmAJ7@/7u05dvpBb6Hezdh4@fv36ndxJN1XbYkFUJT8pwJECgGvm@OgE@zBqv6DTZ37KW2fq@kQ@K2Yf/5wojjCKVI9WN2nEzZh9O@6wWG87ra6docI5migs0IZoZmgX6Afpz9GcYGAwCauFYikscDN5qqxMyC4nlhTRHhQPniqQA8sUB2cesvoBPy@jQ5tGLSVtvy06KRCiVZ6sfrTT@WanyMQsUVp8KFKdWCzWS5YXxVdwtu0mzqber9UbSHegidVNWnbCVmPzelZXcZnGcGTwzecYVec5bb3nn7jAspWH7/T8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Possibly [578 bytes](https://tio.run/##RVBNT9tAEFVPVTmgSj0gwYEJl91NTDZ2XWoMwXz2i9LSD1pLHssKIYBR5FheHwDtfw8zMSErjXbe25mdea98qG8nhTedXk8qyCEvoBoUNyPp@SpcgrovDEA2O5TEBjRs@R4AGgI6@PjhvdtjFAOADncCLqQUKYjSu9uhNtgQMei9/q42zStCbA/2I2uMJWRje3h0uADHJ8cL8OnL5xcA@PX7KQ2nPThoBp5@O0Me2zBMAZ79OP/9959hKjZ4/vPXn4v/9GpIADZqaA/RrUbleDAcSWGE47cFCLUE7MPQOSInkse8lMnwtpL3itn7hTt@4ASBSh1qaU@qK2lUp@ow8HuzUuNUXMwfbGDv1Wss3iy/fbeytrre2nCE5QVsZKG5UaOOKBAiZAmas8yCtVmUAd3ZHOFz1ayBPWQ0/@b5Fl1TjvNaikgolSaDSyNdbzNXaYe3EahbwhEt1EK1Zb7neiqs@/WLE6ScPCirvKgFFqJ7N8kLOU7CMHGdTTdNuCNNWeKYBdbzYTENm06fAA).

Comment: `[1,-1][i>12]` -> `2*(i<13)-1`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 26942 bytes

```
{iii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{iiiii}ddc{dddddd}dddcc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiic{iii}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}cc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiicc{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}cciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}cc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddcccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiicciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}cc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddcccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddcccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccccc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iicc{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddcc{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiicc{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iicc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddcc{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}ii}iiic{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}c{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddcc{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}iiic{dddddd}dddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}iiicdddc{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{{d}i}ddc{{i}d}iicc{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iicc{ddd}ic{iii}dcc{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiicc{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}cc{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}ddc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddc{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiicc{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}cc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}cc{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}cc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{i}iiiiic{iiii}iiiiicc{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiiccccdddc{dddddd}c{iiiiii}cc{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}cc{dddd}dddddc{d}dddddc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddcc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddcc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{iiiiii}iiicc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{{i}d}iic{ddd}icc{iii}dc{{d}i}ddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiicc{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}cccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiic{iiiii}ddcccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddcc{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiicc{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}c{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddcc{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iiicccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{iiiiii}iiicccc{dddddd}dddccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiicc{iiii}iiiiic{dddddd}c{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddc{i}iiiiicc{d}dddddcccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddc{iiiiii}c{dddd}dddddc{{i}dd}dddc{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{{i}}{i}iiiic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddcccccccc{{i}d}iic{{d}i}ddccc{{i}d}iic{{d}}{d}ddddc{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}ccc{iiiiii}ciiicccc{ddddd}iic{d}dddddccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciiicccccc{ddddd}iic
```